# UITabBar width using Storyboard

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uitabbar

I want to get a `UITabBar`'s width in order to get the width of an item.
For this, I'm using:

```
let itemWidth = tabBar.frame.size.width / tabBar.items.count
```

However the width I get seems wrong...

The `tabBar.frame.size.width` gives me the width of the tabBar in the Storyboard depending of the preview...

In other words, if my Storyboard preview is set to **iPad Pro 12.9"**, `tabBar.frame.size.width` will return `1024.0` even if the code is run on an **iPhone 5s**.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITabBar`'s dimensions **will only be accurate** after its `layoutSubviews()` function was executed. Subclass `UITabBarController` and access the tab bar's size in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`.

```
class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController {
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        print(tabBar.frame.width) //this will print the actual width
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome ! Thanks ! Do you have any idea why the value printed before `layoutSubviews` was the as the one shown in the Storyboard ? (if it has an explanation....)

Comment: It's simple: the initial size of a non-programmatical view is **always** the one that was set in Interface Builder.